# Limit max available memory during development in Visual Studio for .NET Core / C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

We deploy our ASP .NET Core application in a Docker container.

We develop it using Visual Studio 2019. Also when we are coding and debugging it, we don't run it in a container.

But we would like to emulate the docker container memory limits as close as possible during development.

Do you have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Its a legitimate question, however i am not sure an answer will be satisfying. Even if you could do this, which i am not sure you can, it wouldn't give you any more benefit (and probably less) then profiling your app. Lets pretend you can, when you hit your limit you would either get degraded performance or a crash (depending on the hows and whys), and you are going to have to profile your app anyway. So in short, if you have memory constraints, you better profile your app and get used to writing minimal allocation code `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I am not sure if it will be possible to simulate the same behaviour as if Docker's limits are reached by just limiting the processes working set, but still, this https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows post and answer and this https://github.com/lowleveldesign/process-governor github repo may help.

Comment: @MichaelRandall: Yeah, we already do that. But it can sometimes help to find out which parts need to be converted to streaming-like patterns and which ones can stay stringbuilder-like ;-)

Comment: @OguzOzgul is this possible to run from a debugging session?

Comment: I think so. A debugging session is a running process with a debugger attached to it :)